# How do I use a Firefox 4 profile on a separate drive/partition

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I have always used a separate partition/drive for Data as well as having a separate partition for my home folder. I have now upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 and I found none of my profiles run under  Classic Ubuntu or Unity. They still run perfectly if I use the 'straight' Firefox 4 firefox-mozilla-build from the Ubuntuzilla PPA.

The error message is:

Firefox  cannot use the profile "??????" because it is in use. To continue, close the running instance of Firefox or choose a different profile.

This message is apparently given if the profile is locked or if the profile can not be found. It is clearly not a stale lock file as it occurs when you try to create a new profile so it would seem firefox cannot find or has access blocked to the Profile.

I have narrowed the problem down even further and my existing profiles will run in the default location ~/.mozilla/firefox or in a sub-folder below that location. I can also create new profiles in the same locations but not elsewhere.

I have edited profiles.ini to see if it is related to the IsRelative addressing and that is not the cause as one can change a relative to absolute location without problems.

I am baffled. Is this a bug in the modifications for Unity compatibility or a security feature which can be enabled/disabled? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from comments below ended up being to change Firefox's AppArmor settings.

Below maintained for history

---

First I would remove the *firefox-mozilla-build*, since Ubuntuzilla is no longer an active project. Also make sure your browser is actually using ~/.mozilla/firefox and not ~/.mozilla/firefox-4.0. Depending on the ppa you are using, the profiles will be cloned to different folders.

I suppose you have already tried to delete the *lock* file under your profile.

As "maco" already pointed out, you can create a symlink for the entire profile folder. If that doesn't work (it should work), then verify the profile paths by opening the *profiles.ini* file with a text editor.

I also recommend using the new standalone [Profile Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Profile_Manager).

Comment: Thanks, The problems is not to do with lockfile - I tried that first.

Comment: I have been using firefox-mozilla-build and first got the problem when I removed it. I have checked profiles.ini and edited it to check IsRelative  as the source of the problems. No firefox-4.0 folder. I am sure the symlink approach will work but I would like to get to bottom of it as I use Unison for transferring and backing up profiles between machines. It still looks as if it is a real restriction on the location of the profile perhaps for a Unity fudge. Has anyone duplicated the problem/feature

Comment: It could be a permission issue. Try the symlink approach, just to make sure Firefox is able to save that in the data drive.

Comment: I have now tried a symlink from .mozilla/firefox to my normal folders on my DATA drive and again I can not access the profile in the folder to which the link has been set although I can use firefox -P to set up an entry in profile.ini which looks correct. Permissions look OK

Comment: And just to make sure I can make a symlink to a folder under .mozilla and use a profile in it by running the old profile manager by firefox -P. If one can not even use a symlink then the common use of a profile on a USB drive carried between machines is ruled out.

Comment: I would check if you have a Firefox profile for AppArmor messing things up.

Comment: We have got there finally. I have found out enough about AppArmor to disable the profile for firefox and everything now works. It looks as if AppArmor is enabled for firefox in 11.04 but not in 10.04 which I have previously been using. Many thanks once more for all your assistance.

Comment: Should I pose a separate question if I need help in modifying the firefox apparmor-profile?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it would be better to post another thread. However, for such kind of topic, I would recommend the Ubuntu forums. Take a look at bodhi.zazen's thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1008906

Answer (score 1):

Create a symlink for the profile.

```
ln -s /Data/.mozilla/firefox ~/.mozilla/firefox
```

Comment: I have now tried a symlink from .mozilla/firefox to my normal folders on my DATA drive and again I can not access the profile in the folder to which the link has been set although I can use firefox -P to set up an entry in profile.ini which looks correct.

Comment: Please also see my comments to lovinglinux